# Angular 2 Custom Pipe cannot read a property of null

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a custom pipe:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'doubleNumber'
})
export class DoubleNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    if(value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return value*2;
    }
  }

}
```

And I declared it in the declaration decorator section at the app.module.ts:

```
declarations: [
AppComponent,
DataDrivenComponent,
DoubleNumberPipe
```

],

Then I created an HTML form to take a number and double it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <p>Number</p>
    <input type="text" #val (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{val.value | doubleNumber}}</p>
    <hr>
      <h1>Forms</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result was only "0" on the page, and the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./DataDrivenComponent class DataDrivenComponent -
>   inline template:37:54 caused by: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54 (anonymous) @
>   application_ref.js:261 ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:334 onInvoke @
>   ng_zone.js:273 ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:333 Zone.run @
>   zone.js:126 (anonymous) @ zone.js:713 ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:367 onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:264 ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:366 Zone.runTask @ zone.js:166 drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:546

And:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./DataDrivenComponent class
>   DataDrivenComponent - inline template:37:54 caused by: Cannot read
>   property 'value' of null ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;

Comment: try this `val?.value`, and show the code of your component

Comment: Nope. It didn't worked with the elvis operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mickdev suggested... is almost correct, but you get NaN error, because you have defined the input type as `text`.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val">
<p *ngIf="val">{{val | doubleNumber}}</p>
```

Remove that, or replace with `type="number"`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="val">
<p *ngIf="val">{{val | doubleNumber}}</p>
```

Comment: It works on the plnkr link but still having the same error. I will set this answer as correct, but still having the same problem

Comment: Could you fork e.g my plunker with your code, I'd be happy to take a look at it :)

Comment: Okay wait for few minutes

Comment: You can see it now

Comment: Did you fork it, then the url changes, so you'd have to give the url :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) in this way:

```
<p>{{val?.value | doubleNumber}}</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Still the same

Answer (score 1):

You should use ngModel in that case. Something like this :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val">
<p *ngIf="val">{{val | doubleNumber}}</p>
```

No need to use keyup, this will auto update your val.

Comment: see my updated answer. I wrapped `val` in conditional block, so it will be evaluated only if the user provide a value.